# Android won't launch in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-api-3, genymotion

I'm following the instructions here:

```
https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/
```

I also use Google API in my application.

So, I click on this button:

[image]

the Android emulator is opened, I go Run as Android application on the project and nothing happens. In the bar below, I get Launching Android 100% and the green bar just won't stop scrolling. It looks like this:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Did you check adb devices to see if your VM is correctly launched and connected?

Comment: The Android emulator is running just fine.

Comment: It looks like an ADT problem, can you add the console output? (Window > Show View > Console)